# Unexpected NameError while running the same script on two different Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to understand why a code that works perfectly well and yields the expected output when ran on an Jupyter Notebook on my local machine through VS Code does not work when I input it into the Jupyter Notebook on my course server.

The only difference between the two runs are that I wrote it outside of a function in VSCode, and it is applied within a function on my course server.

I will copy here the code I am inputting the course server notebook. The only difference between this code and my original code, which works as intended, is that it is contained within a function. But now I get a Name Error.

```
<ipython-input-14-d6abfb2de427> in answer_one()
     34         if re.search(r'[0-9]+',row):
     35             row=re.sub(r'[0-9]+','',row)
---> 36     return row.strip()
     37 
     38     #We now apply it to the whole df, row-wise.

NameError: name 'row' is not defined
```

Here is the code as contained within the function in the context of the server notebook:

```
def answer_one():
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import re 

    #First import the file
    path="assets/Energy Indicators.xls"
    df_energy=pd.read_excel(path)
    #Only keep relevant information, localized by looking at Excel file in Excel, then treating dropping useless columns and renaming.
    df_energy=df_energy[17:244]
    df_energy = df_energy.drop(df_energy.columns[[0,1]], axis=1)
    df_energy.rename(columns={'Unnamed: 2' : 'Country', 
    'Unnamed: 3' : 'Energy Supply', 
    'Unnamed: 4' : 'Energy Supply Per Capita', 
    'Unnamed: 5' : '%Renewable'}, 
    inplace=True)
    #Replace all NAs to np.nan
    df_energy.replace('...', np.nan, inplace=True)
    
    # Convert Energy Supply (currently expressed in petajoules) in gigajoules (*1 million)
    df_energy['Energy Supply']=df_energy['Energy Supply']*1000000

    #Search for any parentheses in the Country series
    series=df_energy['Country'].to_string()
    result = re.search(r'\(\)',series)
    print(result)

    #Having not found any parentheses, we will now try to find numbers.
    result = re.search(r'[0-9]+',series)
    print(result)

    #We now write a function to clean.
    def clean(row):
        if re.search(r'[0-9]+',row):
            row=re.sub(r'[0-9]+','',row)
        return row.strip()

    #We now apply it to the whole df, row-wise.
    df_energy['Country']=df_energy['Country'].apply(clean)
    #Convert explicitly requested names

    df_energy['Country'].replace({"Republic of Korea": "South Korea",
            "United States of America": "United States",
            "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland": "United Kingdom",
            "China, Hong Kong Special Administrative Region": "Hong Kong",
            'Iran (Islamic Republic of)': 'Iran',
            'Bolivia (Plurinational State of)' : 'Bolivia',
            'Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)' : 'Venezuela'},
            inplace = True)    
    
    ### Load GDP data from assets/world_bank.csv
    ### Call it GDP
    ### Skip the header (df starts at 5 end at 269)
    path = 'assets/world_bank.csv'
    GDP = pd.read_csv(path,skiprows=[0,1,2,3])
    GDP = GDP[['Country Name', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010','2011', '2012','2013','2014','2015']]
    GDP = GDP.rename( columns = {'Country Name':'Country'})
    change_names = {"Korea, Rep.": "South Korea", 
    "Iran, Islamic Rep.": "Iran",
    "Hong Kong SAR, China": "Hong Kong"}
    GDP.replace({"Country": change_names}, inplace = True)
    
    #Load ScimEn
    ScimEn = pd.read_excel('assets/scimagojr-3.xlsx')
    
    #Performing the merger and setting index to the intersection column
    df=pd.merge(df_energy, GDP, how='inner',on='Country')
    df=pd.merge(df, ScimEn[ScimEn['Rank']<16], how='inner',on='Country')
    df.set_index('Country', inplace=True)
    df.sort_values('Rank', inplace=True)
    dfcolumns=['Rank', 'Documents', 'Citable documents', 'Citations', 'Self-citations',
      'Citations per document', 'H index', 'Energy Supply',
      'Energy Supply Per Capita', '%Renewable', '2006', '2007', '2008',
       '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015']
    df2 = df[dfcolumns]
    df = df2
    return df
    
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

**Do you have any idea what this error comes from, and how I may go about fixing it?**
Many thanks in advance. Again, the code works fine in my VSCode version, where it is not contained within a function answer_one but rather directly inputted into a succession of cells.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. `return row.strip()` isn't inside the `clean()` function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.   You need to fix your indent.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried this, and will edit the main question to reflect the correction. Even with indentation apparently correct, the same error comes when I try to run the cell, unfortunately!

Comment: Well, we cannot see cells here, but with your current edit, you have a function definition inside another, which doesn't seem necessary. You should move your clean function to its own cell

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks! That is what I usually do but in the assignment, for autograding purposes I guess, we are not allowed to create cells. In my original script, I did write it in a different cell (although in the same sequential order as what you see above) thinking it would not impact the result?